# How to set a lock by thread in priority order with OpenMP C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I assume that when several threads execute an omp_set_lock(&lock) the first thread will acquire the lock and the other will be blocked and placed in a queue until the lock is released.
When the lock is released the next thread in the queue will acquire the lock and so on.

I want tasks to acquire the lock in order according to the task id if possible. If not possible just give in.
An example could be:

```
omp_lock_t lock;
int prio;

bool set_lock(int task_id) {
   if (!omp_test_lock(&lock))
     if (task_id<prio) {
       prio=task_id;// 1
       omp_set_lock(&lock);// 2
       // The problem here is that prio might just be changed between 1 and 2 and lock set
// by another thread
       return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Is there a solution to the problem?

Comment: This really sounds like an XY Problem. What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish by having the threads acquire the lock in a particular order? Why have you chosen to use a shared lock for this, rather than a synchronization primitive which could more explicitly do that?

Comment: I have a set of objects with a lock and a prio variable. A thread processes 5 of these objects together if and only if none of the locks are acquired by another thread. It could lead to a deadlock like the dining philosophers. My solution when trying to acquire a lock is to look at the prio for the lock taken. If prio<task_id the thread will give in and release all its acquired locks. The thread will then do something else.

Comment: It sounds like you just need each thread to acquire locks in priority order (priority of the locks, not priority of the threads) then, to break the possibility of circular hold-and-wait.

Comment: you are right  i will vote you up